# Javascript function is mutating parameter with node v14.7.0

Tags: node.js

Node.js is mutating the number value passed into the **test** function.  Any idea why and how to fix?  Thank you!

```js
const val1  = 61368443939717130;
const val2 = 861368443939717130;
const val3 = 161368443939717130;

const test = (v) => {
  console.log(v);
}

test(val1);
test(val2);
test(val3);

// Output:
// 61368443939717130
// 861368443939717100
// 161368443939717120
```

Comment: Nothing is being mutated here. You're just hitting the limits of how big a number in JS can be. Look up `bigInt`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the number `161368443939717130` is bigger than the maximum safe integer that Javascript can represent, which is provided by the constant Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER. When working with big numbers you should always check that the values are below the limit, or otherwise you will get unexpected results. See more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

Answer (score 0):

Your numbers are out of range for javascript.

The max number javascript can handle is `9007199254740991` (9,007,199,254,740,991 or ~9 quadrillion).

It is represented by the MAX_SAFE_INTEGER variable. The reasoning behind that number is that JavaScript uses [double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) numbers as specified in [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) and can only safely represent integers between -(2^53 - 1) and 2^53 - 1.

Use `BigInt`, which has no practical upper limit. But `BigInt` can’t handle decimals.
This means that if you convert from a Number to a BigInt and backward again, you can lose precision.

```
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
// 9007199254740991
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 10)
// 9007199254741000
console.log(BigInt(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) + 10n) 
// 9007199254741001n
```